# liquibase - update changelog.yaml file with latest database changes

Tags: liquibase

At production, database updated with liquibase changelog.yaml and database updated successfully.

We have made several changes (as part of several enhancements) to the database schema like new table creation, altering table columns and creating constraints and so on.

Is there any way to update changelog.yaml automatically with latest database schema changes? (need to append to the existing yaml file, not to re-create from scrach.  so very less impact on production transitional data)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look at the command `diffChangeLog`. It requires that you have two different databases to compare. One way to do this is to use the `snapshot` command to create a JSON formatted database snapshot before making the changes to the schema manually, then make your changes, and then use `diffChangelog` to compare the snapshot to the current state. Alternatively, you can compare two live database instances.